# AfterUpdate On ComboBox: Display selection without requiring other action

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a combo box that has approval codes in it.
I created an AfterUpdate event so that when the user selects the approval code today's date will be placed in another field.

The problem is when I tab out of the combo box the date doesn't display in the field unless I click in that field or save the record.
I know I can do a `Me.Refresh` after the code, but I don't want to save the record until the user is done with everything they need to input.

```vb
Private Sub AppArch_AfterUpdate()
    Me.DATE_RCVD_ARCH = Date
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must reference textbox name so if field and textbox have same name, then your existing code should work and new value display immediately. Apparently that is not the case. I always name controls different from field, like tbxDateRA. Then code can be:

`Me.tbxDateRA = Date`
or
`Me!tbxDateRA = Date`
but use the first to trigger intellisense tips.

Comment: The first one directly accesses a compile-time, implicitly defined public field - it's a direct member call. The second is deceptive because it reads like a weird member call, but anything that follows the `!` bang operator *is actually a string literal* and the syntax is a roundabout way to dereference a control that's just right there, because it does it via implicit default member calls, so the second is equivalent to `Me.Controls("txtDateRA").Value = Date`. Use the first, forget the second one exists ;-)